# mediaReader.readPacket() blocks while trying to read rtsp stream in Xuggler

Tags: java, ffmpeg, rtsp, xuggler, xuggle

I am trying to download a video (with a Xuggler 5.4 library) from rtsp stream to a file using the code below.

```
    String inputSource = "rtsp://[ip-address]:[port]/user=[username]&[password]=password&channel=1&stream=1.sdp";
    String outputFilename = "d:/downloadedrtsp.flv";
    try {
        IContainerFormat inFormat = IContainerFormat.make();
        inFormat.setInputFormat("h246");

        IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputSource);
        mediaReader.setQueryMetaData(false);

        IMediaWriter mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename, mediaReader);
        mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);

        logger.info("before reading");
        IError error;
        while ((error = mediaReader.readPacket()) == null) {
            logger.info("reading packet");
        }
        logger.info("error: " + error.getDescription());
        logger.info(error.getType());
        logger.info(error.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is that after printing "before reading" the code just stop executing, and after a long time it prints me three lines from logger:

> error: Unknown error
>
> ERROR_EOF
>
> Unknown error

Stream works great when i am opening it in the VLC media player. I am shure there is some mistake in my mediaReader configuration, but i don't know where exactly as i have a very little experience working with videos. Here is some information about video, taken from VLC:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything works as expected.
The error type `ERROR_EOF` marks the end of the input stream (see [the documentation](http://www.xuggle.com/public/documentation/java/api/com/xuggle/mediatool/IMediaReader.html#readPacket())).
The long time you program "stop executing" is the time it takes for Xuggler to convert the video frames (it actually doesn't "stop", just iterate through the `while` loop).